# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to invoke a method but in meantime it give me an error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

**Function Declaration**

```
datahandler= (val1,val2) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        dataNew:
          this.state.dataNew=== {val1} ? {val2} : {val1}
      },
      () => {
        this.getNew();
      }
    );
  };
```

**Function Calling**

```
<Table.HeaderCell onClick={this.datahandler('name asc','name desc')}>
  Click Me to Call
</Table.Headercell>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are invoking `this.sortHandler` directly on render, which will cause `setState` to be invoked, which in turn results in a new render, and the indefinite loop continues.

You want to give `onClick` a function that should be invoked when the click event occurs instead.

```
<Table.HeaderCell
  onClick={() => this.sortHandler("companyName asc", "companyName desc")}
>
  Click Me to Call
</Table.HeaderCell>
```